# clicking on the select option how to show hidden field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

***I am working on php how to show hidden field?***

I have **bp_scholarship_enq** table in my database and this database i have occupation field  i want to add new occupation in my database how i do it?

```
 <script>
    function showss(ids)
        {

            var  idss=ids;

            if(idss=="other")

            document.getElementById(idss).style.display='block';

        }   


</script>

<?php
echo "<select name='occupation' id='link_block' value='Source' style='width:196%'>
                      <option>select occupation </otpion>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bp_scholarship_enq";
$info = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($info)) 
    echo "<option > '" . @$row["occupation"] . "'</option>";


echo '<option onClick="showss('.input_field.')">other</option>';
echo "</select>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="other" id="input_field" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hidden fields are not meant to be visible. You could use a textbox and set its visiblity to false in css and make visible it on changing the select option.

```
<input type="text" name="other" id="input_field" style="display:none"/>

    <select name='occupation' id='link_block' value='Source' style='width:196%' onChange="showText(this.selectedIndex);">
    ...............
    ...............
<option value="other">other</option>
    </select>

<script>
  function showtext(ind){
         var selectBox = document.getElementById('link_block');
         if(selectBox.options[ind].value=="other"){
                   document.getElementById('input_field').style.display = "block";
         }else{
                    document.getElementById('input_field').style.display = "none";
         }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input type="hidden" name="other" id="input_field" />
```

Make it:

```
<input id="otherOccupation" class="hide" name="other" id="input_field" />
```

With hide being a class that sets visibility:hidden;

Then have some jquery to remove that class when the user selects "other"

```
$("#otherOccupation").removeClass("hide")
```